# Janrain Engage (aka RPX) for iPhone auth_info token problem

Tags: iphone, janrain, rpx

I'm having an issue with Janrain Engage (specifically for the iPhone).  I'm using the server-side tokenUrl option to complete my authentication process.  To configure this way, I initialize my jrEngage object like this:

```
    self.jrEngage = [JREngage jrEngageWithAppId:appId andTokenUrl:tokenUrl delegate:self];
```

Since I've specified a tokenUrl, the Janrain library automatically posts the one-time auth_info token to the URL I've specified.  My server then uses this token to request the auth_info data from Janrain.  I'm using the Janrain [example](https://github.com/janrain/Janrain-Sample-Code/blob/master/php/rpx-token-url.php) code to make this tokenized request from my PHP server.

For some reason, this works fine when the "One time use auth_info tokens" setting is off.  When I turn it on, however, I get error code 2 "Data not found"...  I want the security of the single-use tokens. Have I already used the token somehow?

Note: I can see that the SDK is indeed passing the token correctly to my tokenUrl, so that doesn't seem to be the problem.

If it matters, I'm using the CodeIgniter framework on the server side.

Thanks,
Steve

Answer (score 0):

Steve,
<strike>Token URLs used with the iOS library (or the upcoming Android library) require multiple use tokens -- the NSDictionary parameter of jrAuthenticationDidSucceedForUser is populated with data gathered by using the token.</strike>

Edit:
In May we updated Engage to address this issue, auth_info token URLs for the native mobile libraries no longer require multiple use auth_info tokens.

Comment: Janrain also has a support forum we monitor more closely: https://support.janrain.com/forums/243275-iphone-library-q-a